# CSS Border Colour Into 4 Colours

Tags: html, css, border

Is there any way that I can have 4 different colours on one side of a border in CSS? I currently have

```
#header
{
border-color:#88a9eb;
}
```

I want to have a border of 4 solid colours, with a 25% split on each, Is this something that is possible?

I want to make a solid version of this without the white bits in between.

[image]

Comment: On all 4 sides or only one side?

Comment: on only 1 side of the border

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `border-image` property to create a gradient border with 4 colors. Normally gradients move gradually from one color to another and it produces a blur like effect but setting the [**color-stops**](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#color-stop-syntax) (the percentage values) such that the end-point of one color is same as the starting point of the next color makes the colors come to a hard stop and thus end up producing block like effects.

The border can be set to the required side by changing the `border-image-width` and the direction of the gradient. For example, top & bottom borders would need the gradient to go from left **to right** while left & right borders would need the gradient to go from top **to bottom**.

The gradients use percentage values for the size (and color-stop) and hence they are responsive by default and can adapt automatically even if the container's dimensions change.

The only drawback to using `border-image` is the [poor browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-image) for this property at present. IE10- do not support this property.

```css
.bordered-top {
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-width: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
}
.bordered-bottom {
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-width: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
}
.bordered-left {
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-width: 0px 0px 0px 4px;
}
.bordered-right {
  border-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  border-image-width: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: beige;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- library added only for old browser support -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class='bordered-top'>Border only on top</div>
<div class='bordered-bottom'>Border only on bottom</div>
<div class='bordered-left'>Border only on left</div>
<div class='bordered-right'>Border only on right</div>
```

---

For IE10+ support, you could mimic the same behavior by using gradients for the `background-image` property instead of `border-image` like in the below snippet.

Unlike with `border-image`, here the side on which the border is applied cannot be controlled using the `border-image-width` and we have to use `background-position` instead to position the image at the required position.

The `background-size` determines the thickness of the border. For **top & bottom borders**, the size in x-axis should be 100% and that in y-axis is the thickness of the border. For **left & right borders**, the size in y-axis should be 100% and that in x-axis is the thickness of the border.

```css
.bordered-top {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  background-size: 100% 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.bordered-bottom {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  background-size: 100% 4px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
.bordered-left {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  background-size: 4px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
.bordered-right {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(139, 191, 64) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 25%, rgb(230, 27, 33) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 50%, rgb(124, 196, 236) 75%, rgb(254, 181, 17) 75%);
  background-size: 4px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 0%;
}
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: beige;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- library added only for old browser support -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<div class='bordered-top'>Border only on top</div>
<div class='bordered-bottom'>Border only on bottom</div>
<div class='bordered-left'>Border only on left</div>
<div class='bordered-right'>Border only on right</div>
```

Comment: Thorough answer, great that you added examples for all four sides for the OP

Answer (score 8):

You can use `box-shadow` and `after` `psuedo-element` to do this

What I did:

I first created an `:after` element on the bottom, then added `box-shadow`s horizontally with different `colors`

If you want to change the strength of the border simply give more height to the `:after` element

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: grey;
}
div:after {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 50px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 50px 0 0 0 red, 100px 0 0 0 orange, 150px 0 0 0 green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Same thing on a larger `div` will be like this

```css
div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  background: orange;
  position: relative;
}
div:after {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  box-shadow: 100px 0 0 0 darkred, 200px 0 0 0 red, 300px 0 0 0 yellow, 400px 0 0 0 tomato;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Really creative approach ! <3

Comment: Will this work if the widths aren't fixed, but in percentages?

Comment: No i don't think that will be possible @Vucko

Answer (score 4):

I have taken what harry had and amended it to suit my needs. I now have:

```
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #8CC63F 0%, #006F3B 25%, #ED1C24 25%, #9B1B1E 50%, #85CDEC 50%, #217EC2 75%, #FFC20E 75%, #F04E23 100%);
  border-image-slice: 3;
  border-image-width: 0px 0px 4px 0px;
  border-image-repeat: round;
```

This is the best solution for my needs.

Comment: It is good that you were able to modify it to suit your needs. The thanks notes are generally not required in question/answer and hence I have removed it out. Don't forget to mark one answer as accepted (it could be your own answer or mine or any other in here) as that is SO's way of marking a question as solved/answered :)

Answer (score 1):

Complicated but cool solution: Use SVG (e.g. `<svg>` tag), add 4 paths, assign different `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-color` attributes.

Simpler and still cool solution: Try [border-image](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp). (See Harry's answer)

Very simple solution if you just need one border: Create an image, but it as the background image, repeat it only on one axis, position it at the edge of the container, e.g. (for bottom border)

```
.container {
    background-image: url(image.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
.solid{

  width: 300px;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, red 25%, blue 25%, blue 50%, green 50%, green 75%, orange 75%);
  border-image-slice: 4;


}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/tfpto6n7/)

Comment: I know this is a simple problem and you could have come up with the code yourself but the way you have used the same `width` the same `border-image-slice` and the same order for colors cries of plagiarism and copying.

Answer (score 0):

Best solution is with `linear-gradient`. Definitely. 
But someone who's the beginner in this could find this solution useful. By using 2-3-4 colors or even more, this is the right way to do them. Not the best solution for this question, but maybe someone while reading this wants to understand better how do the colors with borders work.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
p.one {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #0000ff;
}

p.two {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000 #0000ff;
}

p.three {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000 #00ff00 #0000ff;
}

p.four {
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ff0000 #00ff00 #0000ff rgb(250,0,255);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p class="one">One-colored border!</p>
<p class="two">Two-colored border!</p>
<p class="three">Three-colored border!</p>
<p class="four">Four-colored border!</p>

</body>
</html>
```