# How to make a double color single border using css?

Tags: css

Guys actually I need help to make a single border double colored. It means a single line 25 % of red and other 75% of blue color using CSS.

My non-working code:

```
element { 
  border-bottom:2px solid red;
  position:relative;
  z-index:999;
  opacity:1;
```

I think it can be possible by `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is no platform for requests as “I can’t do it, please do it for me.”

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS triangle custom border color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450733/css-triangle-custom-border-color)

Comment: This can also be achieved using `border-image` and gradients like mentioned here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781360/css-border-colour-into-4-colours/32781447#32781447. The browser support is very low in IE (IE11+) but this is the ideal way to create border with more than one color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div class="element"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.element {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #00f;
    position: relative;
}

.element::before {
    background-color: #f00;
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Demo:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KittMedia/pfoxmj80/)

Comment: Thanks for an great help.