# How to create border bottom with 2 different color?

Tags: css, styles, border, underline

I need to create border bottom with two different color like below picture

[image]

How do I create the CSS?

Comment: Use a `linear-gradient` as border or background image (or) place a smaller sized pseudo element on top. This thread should help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781360/css-border-colour-into-4-colours/32781447#32781447 (although it has more colors)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use css pseudo classes i.e `:after` or `:before`.

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ccc;
}

h3:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: brown;
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  bottom: -2px;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Last Recent Post</h3>
```

And you can use css gradient as well:

```css
h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

h3:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, brown 50px, #ccc 50px);
  height: 2px;
  content: '';
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<h3>Last Recent Post</h3>
```

Comment: incase if someone wants the width of the underline to be as wide as the words "Last Recent Post", just add the line, "display: inline-block;" to the deifnition of "h3"

Comment: Great solution. I used only two lines of this code for what i need, split bottom border by half.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the accepted solution is the bottom border has a fixed width of `50px;` , hence it does not respect the length of the text. The more efficient solution would be the following:

```
<h2>
  <span>Text length doesn't matter</span>
</h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 { 
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: lightgray;
}

span {
 border-bottom-width: 3px;
 border-bottom-style: solid;
 border-bottom-color: brown;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 0 -2px 0;
 padding: 30px 3px;
}
```

The result will look like the following: JsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/uyzndpvs/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

use **box-shadow** with **zero blur**

**syntax :** 
*box-shadow : x-offset y-offset blur radius color*

**example :** *box-shadow 0 0 0 1em red , 0 0 0 2em orange.*

this will emulate a border of 1em red border and then a 1em orange border.

**Note** that orange color has a radius of 2em ( because half of it will be covered by red color)